# RAILS_ENVを設定しているのに`rake db:seed`実行時にローカルを参照して失敗する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

以下のサイトでも質問済みですが、回答がないためこちらでも質問いたします。
https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/rake-db-seed-cant-connect-to-remote-db/83827

## 再現手順

### database.yaml

AWS RDSを使用しています。

```yml
# database.yml
staging:
  primary:
    adapter: postgis
    encoding: utf8
    database: app_db
    pool: 5
    username: user
    password: <passwd>
    host: <remote_host>
    port: 5432
```

### db作成

コンテナのシェルに入り、`rake db:create:primary, rake db:migrate:primary`を実行してデータベースを作成しました。

### seedの実行

`rake db:seed`を実行したところ以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Tasks: TOP => db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

`db:abort_if_pending_migrations`がローカルを参照していてタスクが落ちます。
`db:abort_if_pending_migrations:primary`というタスクもありこちらを手動で実行した場合は成功しています。

rake aboutで`staging`が使用されていることを確認済みです。
なぜ、RDSを参照できないのでしょうか？

## 環境

Ruby 3.0.6p216
Rails 6.1.7.4